# I'm trying to make a ListViewExtensions class but getting some errors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListViewControl lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.SmallIcon;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListViewControl : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewControl()
            {
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        public static class ListViewExtensions
        {
            public static ListViewItemCollection AddRange(this ListViewItemCollection source, WindowSnapCollection windows)
            {
                //Create a ListViewItem for each object and set the 
                //various properties appropriately
                source.AddRange(from w in windows
                                select new ListViewItem(w.ToString())
                                {
                                    Tag = w
                                });

                return source;
            }

            public static WindowSnap GetWindowSnap(this ListViewItem source)
            {
                return source.Tag as WindowSnap;
            }

            public static WindowSnap GetSelectedWindowSnap(this ListView source)
   {
       return source.SelectedItem?.GetWindowSnap();
   }

            //Add more methods as needed
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The errors are on the lines

```
public static ListViewItemCollection AddRange(this ListViewItemCollection source, WindowSnapCollection windows)
```

Error   16  The type or namespace name 'ListViewItemCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
return source.SelectedItem?.GetWindowSnap();
```

Error   18  'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   19  No overload for method 'GetWindowSnap' takes 0 arguments

Comment: checkout the documentation - [MSDN ListView.ListViewItemCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to fully qualify some class names.

The class ListViewItemCollection is defined in ListView. So you need to fully qualify it with ListView.ListViewItemCollection.

```
public static ListView.ListViewItemCollection AddRange(
    this ListView.ListViewItemCollection source, 
    WindowSnapCollection windows)
```

WindowSnap and WindowSnap collection are not part of .NET, and you don't provide the definition so it's not clear how to use them. Figure out where they are defined and use the full class name, including namespace. Replace all occurrences of WindowSnap with `Namespace.WindowSnap`, and same goes for WindowSnapCollection.

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx) on fully qualified names for more info.

Comment: You right this is the WindowSnapCollection.cs code http://pastebin.com/ZGydKNWi and this is the WindowSnap.cs code http://pastebin.com/8nCDhT9U

Comment: OK it's in the same namespace as the rest of your code. Is it in the same project? Surely the compiler has already asked you this, but: "The type or namespace name 'WindowSnap' could not be found (**are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**)"

Comment: Your two code files in pastebin must either be in the same project as your problematic code, or if they are in a different project, you must add a reference to that project from your project with the code above, or move them into the same project.